# How to rotate views in module?

Tags: views, javascript

I have created a views that works as a slider (title, image, read more).

And now I need some slideshow sow it rotates the views content from newsest to oldest with some transition animation.

I want to use the existing Views I have created and styled already, just to fade out fade in or some more fancy animation.

Any advice how to do that? Any views additional module that can do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Views Slideshow](http://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow)

> Views Slideshow can be used to create a slideshow of any content (not
>   just images) that can appear in a View. Powered by jQuery, it is
>   heavily customizable: you may choose slideshow settings for each View
>   you create.

Comment: The views slideshow has always worked great for me. The only downside is when you are displaying multiple items at one, let say 2 items,and you have an uneven number of elements in the view, it does not wrap round at the end, to always show 2 item, but rather it displays the last item by itselv, and then starts over :(

Comment: @KristofferMortensen i usually limit the number of items to `1`. Or try making a templete for the view and do some magic.